# How to print the compilation directory recored in linux elf binary?

Tags: linux, gdb, elf

The gdb docs say the compilation directory may be recorded in the executable file https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html

> Executable programs sometimes do not record the directories of the
>   source files from which they were compiled, just the names. Even when
>   they do, the directories could be moved between the compilation and
>   your debugging session.

Assuming the executable file records the compilation directory. How to print the compilation directory ?

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
cd /tmp
gcc -g t.c
readelf -Wwi a.out | grep DW_AT_comp_dir

    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x2ab): /tmp
```